# Are zinc & copper extracted from its ore using cyanide salt?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, metallurgy

In my textbook, the extraction of Zinc is done from $\ce{ZnS}$ and copper from Cuprous oxide, so neither of extracting procedures involve the use of $\ce{CN^-}$ salts.

Thinking further, both Zn(II) and Cu(II) form complexes with $\ce{CN-}$.The complex of copper can be reduced by zinc (or any other more reactive metal) to obtain Cu(s)(very much like Mac Arthur Forest Process for Ag/Au). I do not think a more reactive metal than zinc can be used to reduce its complex as they'll react with water.
Accordingly, copper should be the answer but the answer is zinc. Can you please explain this?

Comment: Why would they need to be converted to cyanide complexes if the existing processes work? Note that cyanide are poisonous, so better to avoid them.

Comment: I apologise but I came across a question asking which of Cu,Zn,Ag or Au are not extracted using cyanide salts.It was a single answer correct type and hence I was confused between Cu and Zn knowing that Mac Arthur Forest Process is used for Ag,Au.Can you please help me with the comparison between Cu and Zn.

Comment: I have added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Zinc and copper are primarily consider contaminants in gold/silver extraction and during cyanidation, zinc and copper can complex with cyanide forming respective complexes thus wasting cyanide and technically, you can recover zinc and copper from this complex but the idea doesn't seem feasible and as the method are cost-heavy, ineffective and not to mention that cyanide is toxic in the first place. The below papers will help describe the point in details.

- O. Alonso-González, F. Nava-Alonso, A. Uribe-Salas, *Copper removal from cyanide solutions by acidification*, Minerals Engineering, Volume 22, Issue 4,
  **2009**, DOI: [10.1016/j.mineng.2008.09.004](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S089268750800229X).
- Feng Xie, David Dreisinger & Fiona Doyle (**2013**) *A Review on Recovery of Copper and Cyanide From Waste Cyanide Solutions*, Mineral Processing and Extractive Metallurgy Review, 34:6, 387-411, DOI: [10.1080/08827508.2012.695303](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/08827508.2012.695303?journalCode=gmpr20)
- Bao Guo, Yongjun Peng, Yuliang Mai, *The effect of zinc cyanide on the flotation of gold from pyritic ore*, Minerals Engineering, Volume 85,
  **2016**, [10.1016/j.mineng.2015.10.023](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0892687515301199).
- E.Y. Yazici, F. Ahlatci, E. Yilmaz, O. Celep, H. Deveci, *Precipitation of zinc from cyanide leach solutions using Trimercapto-s-triazine (TMT)*,
  Hydrometallurgy, Volume 191, **2020**, 105206, DOI: [10.1016/j.hydromet.2019.105206](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304386X19304505).

Even the idea of extracting zinc and copper from its ore through cyanide doesn't seem practical and there are already better ways known. Nonetheless, people still try. Here is a [patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US3403020A/en) of extracting copper through cyanide.